# BST in-order recursion: Finding the first node that's greater than K

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

My code seems to run til the end (thus returning None) rather than stopping when the subtree is found.

```
def first_greater_than_k(tree, k):
    if not tree: 
        return None

    first_greater_than_k(tree.left, k)

    if tree.data > k:
        return tree
        
    first_greater_than_k(tree.right, k)
```

Comment: what programming language is this?

Comment: it is python...

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not returning any value in **first_greater_than_k** function. Also, if you have a BST (Binary Search Tree) you can do a lot better than a linear search.

Problem: Find first node that is greater than K while traversing the tree.

```py
def first_greater_than_k(tree, k):
    if not tree: 
        return None
    if tree.data > k:
        return tree
    return first_greater_than_k(tree.right, k)
```

You don't need to recurse left child of tree as values stored there are always lower than tree's value. The running time is `O(h)` where `h` is height of the tree.

Also, a more useful question would be (maybe that's what you asked and we didn't get it):
Find first node that is greater than K if we do in-order traversal.

We can solve it using BST property of the values stated in the book *Introduction to Algorithms* (Cormen, page 287), 3rd Edition:

> Let *x* be a node in a binary search tree. If *y* is a node in the left subtree
> of *x*, then *y.key* ≤ *x.key*. If *y* is a node in the right subtree of *x*, then
> *y.key* ≥ *x.key*.

```py
def first_greater_than_k(tree, k):
    if not tree: 
        return None
    if k < tree.data:
        x = first_greater_than_k(tree.left, k)
        return x if x else tree
    return first_greater_than_k(tree.right, k)
```

This code also has a running time of `O(h)` where `h` is height of the tree.

Comment: Thank you Eloy! I have the 2nd Edition and I found it on p257 :). You're right, the problem was to do in-order traversal.  I was looking for a recursive solution, just to understand recursion better. Anyway your answer is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Original answer without recursion:

```
def first_greater_than_k(tree, k):
    subtree, first_so_far = tree, None

    while subtree:
        if subtree.data > k:
            first_so_far, subtree = subtree, subtree.left
        else:
            subtree = subtree.right
    
    return first_so_far
```

Answer (score 0):

> By the code I can guess that you want to return the subtree whose
> root's value is greater than K.

For that case, you can really improve search-run-time complexity by going into the correct halve. The idea, is, to split the tree in two halves and select the correct halve based on the value of K.

Note: I don't know the language you are using, ignore the syntactical error.

```
def first_greater_than_k(tree, k):
    if not tree: 
        return None

    if tree.data < k
        return first_greater_than_k(tree.left, k)
    
    if(tree.data > k)
        return tree;
        
    return first_greater_than_k(tree.right, k)
```

Overall runtime complexity would be O(log N) where N is the number of node in the Tree.